# When to use wait.until in Appium?

Tags: automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I just started developing a test automation for an iOS app using Appium. I have to click several buttons in the app one after another with different XPath/Accessability ids.

I wondered, when to use the `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf Element)` expression.

Example:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"app\"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeTabBar/XCUIElementTypeButton[3]")));
```

Should I check every time before I click a button if this button is actually visible or existing on the current state of the app or is this just unnecessary and time-wasting?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use ExpectedConditions in two case:

1. Screen load takes long, so you not ending up trying to click something that has not loaded yet. If you find your tests flaky (sometimes pass some times fails) then this probably the main reason why it happens
2. If you have something like ajax on your screen you want to make sure the data is changed on the page. (Example is you created a post on Facebook, and want to make sure content displayed)